# Random Images On Websites.. Goes Away When I Clear My Cache

Tags: google-chrome, security, malware

I'm facing a very weird problem. I'm using Windows 10 and Google Chrome Version 47.0.2526.80 m

The problem is that while browsing the web, sometimes one or more images of a site (any random site) is replaced by a dummy image. Usually this dummy image is a porn-related image or some "Indian Movie Media" related.

If I right-click > open image in a new tab. The dummy image is still there. If I refresh with cache cleared. The image is gone and is replaced with the original image used on the site.

I'm experiencing this problem for the past 5 to 6 months.

Where do the problem lies?

Currently active extensions:-

AdBlock

Advanced REST Client

Capture, Explain and Send Screenshots

Checker Plus for Gmail

Dimensions Legacy

Feedly

Google Dictionary (by Google)

Nimbus Screenshot App

Page Load Time

Toggl Button

I haven't listed disabled extensions.

Comment: you got something nasty for sure.... Try some virus checkers.